# SQL Server high volume update on one field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am building a VoIP switch and I am going to be doing an insert using a SQL stored procedure.
I need to update the user table "balance field" each time I update the history table.  Due to it being a switch I can have hundreds of updates each second.
I wanted to know the best way to update a field with out dead locks and with out wrong info.
I will be using MS sql server 2012.

Comment: Assuming you are inserting into the history table, you may consider using a trigger to update the user balance.

Answer (score 1):

Partition the user table into evenly sized partitions - SQL 2012 allows 10000 of them. That way the updates are distributed over many allocation units instead of just one. Then add the WITH(ROWLOCK) hint to the update query.

To kick off the actual update you could use a trigger.

Comment: If I add RowLock and that field needs to be update very fast will I not get decklocks

Comment: deadlock require two lock resources. Most of the time they are caused by accessing two table in different orders within a transaction. -- If you follow the above advise and don't do anything else inside the same transaction you are most likely fine. However, I cannot give a definitive answer without knowing the whole system.